# C# Winforms Fastest Way To Query MS Access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

This may be a dumb question, but I wanted to be sure. I am creating a Winforms app, and using c# oledbconnection to connect to a MS Access database. Right now, i am using a "SELECT * FROM table_name" and looping through each row to see if it is the row with the criteria I want, then breaking out of the loop if it is. I wonder if the performance would be improved if I used something like "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=something" so basically use a "WHERE" statement instead of looping through every row?

Comment: Did you tried that?

Comment: Without the `WHERE`, the database transfer more data to your app. This will be more obvious as rows increases, or if your database is hosted on the cloud or somewhere other than local devices. It may take 10 minutes to download all data to the client, but the database is likely to search much faster than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to validate the performance of anything is to test. Otherwise, a lot of assumptions are made about what is the best versus the reality of performance.

With that said, 100% of the time using a WHERE clause will be better than retrieving the data and then filtering via a loop. This is for a few different reasons, but ultimately you are filtering the data on a column before retrieving all of the columns, versus retrieving all of the columns and then filtering out the data. Relational data should be dealt with according to set logic, which is how a WHERE clause works, according to the data set. The loop is not set logic and compares each individual row, expensively, discarding those that don’t meet the criteria.

Don’t take my word for it though. Try it out. Especially try it out when your app has a lot of data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

yes, of course.

if you have a access database file - say shared on a folder. Then you deploy your .net desktop application to each workstation?

And furthermore, say the table has 1 million rows.

If you do this:

```
SELECT * from tblInvoice WHERE InvoiceNumber = 123245
```

Then ONLY one row is pulled down the network pipe - and this holds true EVEN if the table has 1 million rows. To traverse and pull 1 million rows is going to take a HUGE amount of time, but if  you add criteria to your select, then it would be in this case about 1 million times faster to pull one row as opposed to the whole table.

And say if this is/was multi-user? Then again, even on a network - again ONLY ONE record that meets your criteria will be pulled. The only requirement for this "one row pull" over the network? Access data engine needs to have a useable index on that criteria. Of course by default the PK column (ID) always has that index - so no worries there. But if as per above we are pulling invoice numbers from a table - then having a index on that column (InvoiceNumber) is required for the data engine to only pull one row. If no index can be used - then all rows behind the scenes are pulled until a match occurs - and over a network, then this means significant amounts of data will be pulled without that index across that network (or if local - then pulled from the file on the disk).